# Dualboot: I can access Ubuntu, but not Windows

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows

today I installed Ubuntu in a new partition. I can boot Ubuntu, but not Windows. Here's a video showing the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xweX5vb8t4

Is there a solution or all my Windows-related data is gone?

Greetings!

EDIT: Boot-Info pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/r1XnnqGj

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the Windows boot loader has been replaced by a copy of GRUB. Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. (Boot Repair is related to Boot Info, but the latter hasn't been updated in ages, so the former is more likely to produce complete information.)

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: I added the link of the information I got from Boot-Info (Boot Repair would not link my posts, screenshot here: http://imgur.com/a/KXZXT).